# Merging from wrong changeset in some circumstances

Tags: tfs, merge

I have a main branch and a dev branch in TFS. I merged changes from the main branch up into the dev branch fine. Now when I try merging up again it says there is nothing to merge.

However when I merge down from the dev branch to the main branch, it magically decides that a bunch of files have differences (which are only present in the main branch). Why does it decide this? Because TFS is comparing using the wrong changelist version from the dev branch! It is using the second to last changelist, not the latest one like I asked!

Sure I could resolve this by doing a force merge, but then every file in main would be marked as changed when it actually hasn't. What I want is for TFS to actually WORK in a logical way, does anybody know a work-around for this behaviour?

Comment: Please see my answer here and add the necessary diagnostic info to your question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/783674/how-to-branch-and-merge-in-tfs

Comment: Hello @evilfred, our team used to get this occasionally.  It would be great if you could document an answer as it might help others who are also getting the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this question has been asked a long time ago.

First things first, you are working on a dev branch and you have a main branch like the published one, so when you merge up to main you should get all changesets you checked in on dev branch.

If that is not the case, make sure you have nothing in pending changes to make sure you checked your changes in.
I work with a workspace for each branch not sure if you do this, make sure that you are on the workspace of the main branch and right click on dev branch and do the merge accordingly.

Hope this is what you were asking for.