# TFS How does merging work?

Tags: tfs, merge, branching-and-merging

I have a release branch **(RB, starting at C5)** and a changeset on **trunk** (C10) that I now want to merge onto RB.

The file has changes at C3 (common to both), one in CS 7 on RB, and one in C9 (trunk) and one in C10). So the history for my changed file looks like this:

```
    RB:       C5 -> C7
Trunk: C3 ->             C9 -> C10
```

When I merge C10 from trunk to RB, I'd expect to see a merge window showing me 
`C10 | C3 | C7` since C3 is the common ancestor revision and C10 and C7 are the tips of my two branches respectively. However, my merge tool shows me `C10 | C9 | C7`.

My merge tool is configured to show `%1(OriginalFile)|%3(BaseFile)|%2(Modified File)`, so this tells me TFS chose C9 as the base revision.

This is totally unexpected and completely contrary to the way I'm used to merges working in Mercurial or Git. Did I get something wrong or is TFS trying to drive me nuts with merging?

**Is this the default TFS Merge behavior? If so, can you provide insight into why they chose to implement it this way?**

I'm using TFS 2008 with VS2010 as a Client.

Comment: What happens if you use the standard merge tool (so remove the configured user tool)?

Comment: @Ewald Hofman: It's the same thing (besides the default TFS merge utility is crap), so it's definetely unreleated to the merge tool being used.

Comment: @Ewald: Does that make you (or anyone else) able to answer my question?

Comment: @John: TFS 2008. Using it with Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had some similar initial struggles with TFS branching and merging (We have dev, integration, and main branches).

Short version is that you cannot merge directly back from a tip to a common ancestor.

So if C3 was branched to C5, then C7 was branched to C9, what the tool is providing makes sense within the context of how TFS works.  You essentially need to go from C10/C9 to C7 then from C7 to C3.

To put it a different way with a more concrete example, here's how we handle multi-level branching and merging in our projects.

We start with trunk/main.

We then branch to an integration branch.

We then (and this is key) branch from integration into our individual dev branches so we can work on upcoming releases.

As changes are complete in a dev branch, we first reverse integrate by merging from integration to our dev branch (so we pick up everyone else's changes).  We then forward integrate by going from our individual dev branch to the shared integration branch.

Once integration passes QA, we then reverse integrate by merging trunk to integration (just in case there are any hotfixes in main), then forward integrate all of the combined changes in integration down to main.

On release day, we do one last branch from main into a new release branch which we then deploy.

Basically, in TFS you always have to go up and down the branching/merging tree from trunk to limb to branch to leaf - you cannot at any time bypass any step in the branch heirarchy.

Metaphorically, TFS branch and merge is more like as sloth crawling up a tree and slowly down to the end of a branch without ever letting lose it's grip vs. a monkey hopping between branches ;)

Takes a bit of getting used to, but once done (and especially once you're used to the forward integrate/reverse integrate paradigm) it works a treat, especially when you have several folks all doing development and you need to wrap up everyone's changes without having things stomped over.

Hope that helps!

Comment: @Bob Palmer: Thanks for your answer. I am aware of the RI/FI pattern. However, this does not explain why TFS choses C9 as a base revision. I think you may have misenterpreted the sample I've shown. C5 and C7 are changes to the file on my release branch (C5 marks the beginning of the release branch, C7 is a change to the file commited on the release branch).

Comment: Ah now I understand your example better!  I suspect the reason you see C9 as your base instead of C3 is because you branched off at C5, and so it looks like it's grabbing the first committed base post-branch (i.e. C9).  I'll test this out on one of my TFS servers.

Comment: hmm... I went and made a sample file starting and replicated your scenario above - and when I went to put in my second change (your C10), I saw my original file (your C3) as my base, not my C9 equivelant change... so there must be something else up.  For my own benefit - you started with trunk and then branched to RB after Changeset 3, and Changeset 5 represents the first checkin into RB?

Comment: yes, I started with trunk and then branched to RB after Changeset 3 (this created C5).

Comment: Branching and merging in TFS is a cruel mistress... something along the way must have reset where it thought the base was and lost your connection to the C3 - I can get your desired behavior, but then I have the benefit of replicating (in lab conditions) your tree above.

Comment: Ok, many thanks Bob. I have no access to a TFS lab environment, so can't replicate it. I'll just file it under TFS Vodoo.

Comment: @Bob Palmer: I was under the impression I accepted your bounty two hours before it ended, somehow SO didn't register that....

Answer (score 0):

i was looking around this site before and came across to this page, is this helpful?

[How to branch and merge in TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783674/how-to-branch-and-merge-in-tfs)

Comment: sorry Jaanus, this was not entirely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you *might* have a wrong merge methodology, because what you describe is completely possible, and it works for me. But you always have to remember when you start branching off the main branch is to do proper RI (Reverse Integration), and FI (forward integration). Have a search on [codeplex for branching guidelines and best practices](http://tfsbranchingguideiii.codeplex.com/).

In essence, any changes that is dropped back to the main branch have to be RI'd back onto your other branches before merging it back. This is best practice and works every time, after that, you can continue to FI from branch back to main trunk.