# Same code base differences to merge

Tags: tfs

We had 2 projects in TFS with same code base. 2 development teams were working on those. We are now merging the code to a one project and this is not an easy task to do manually.
Before starting development in separate we have not used any functionality that TFS provides to make this sort of work easy. Like branching, labeling or any other.

Can I get some **guideline or best practices to plan** this kind of work so we can adopt it in future to overcome this sort of work.

Link for a **TFS guide for developers** will also be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [TFS Branching Guide](http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/) is probably a good place to start.  It will help you with structuring your source based on different usage scenarios

You might also want to look at answers to this questions: [How to branch and merge in TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/783674/63179)

In regards to a "TFS guide for developers" the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181368.aspx) is a good starting point. Beyond that consider the various books that have been published - there are some good ones out there.